# How to Store Ad Campaign Rules in a database to Query Efficiently?

Tags: mysql, indexing, nosql

I have a MySQL table like below which contains thousands of advertising campaigns.

```
+---------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| int: id | string: name | json: countries  | json:regions | json: platforms   | json: browsers      |
+---------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 1       | Uber Android | ["US","UK","DE"] |              | ["Android"]       |                     |
+---------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 2       | Game X       | ["US"]           |              | ["Android","iOS"] | ["Chrome","Safari"] |
+---------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 3       | Game Y       |                  |              | ["Android"]       |                     |
+---------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

In this table, an empty column means it supports all options (e.g. an empty country means the campaign is available for all countries). So basically when I get a visitor, I can extract user details like country code, region, platform, browser and I want to find all suitable ad campaigns matching to user.

So my question is what's the best approach to store this data for querying for each visitor to get the list of all matching campaign IDs?

Comment: It's generally better to store lists in a separate, normalized table rather than in a single column, although the JSON datatype does provide indexing that makes it more efficient to search them.

Comment: I am not a huge fan of the way you are storing your data.  Using JSON as storage.  IMHO those should be separated tables.  The overhead is negligible, but your logic, as your database grows, won't get confused by having to dig through JSON delimited fields.

Comment: To further my explanation:  Your countries **table** will contain 2 fields.  `country_id` and `country_name` etc ..  Then your entries will look like : `1 | US` `2 | UK` `3 | DE` `4 | ALL`  --  Then you would have a relational table that connects them  `campaign->country_id` -- Per your table above, campaign_id 1 would have 3 entries:  `1->1`  `1->2` `1->3` -- campaign_id 2 would only have one entry `2->1`